Redirect issues after rolling out to production
This week  I rolled my project out to a production state using Firebase app hosting.
Everything went relatively well except for the authentication. Using the application in localhost and dev mode gave me no errors at all and everything worked fine.
Now After creating an account and after signing in I this issue where i get redirected to:
https:// mydomain /sign-in?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8080%2Fdashboard
What happens is that I get stuck in what appears to be the sign in screen.
I get this error:
clerk.browser.js:2 Clerk: Redirect URL https://0.0.0.0:8080/dashboard is not on one of the allowedRedirectOrigins, falling back to the default redirect URL.
In my clerk dashboard I've configured my domain correctly (as far as I can see) and same goes for the firebase app hosting dashboard.
these are some .env variables:
variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_FALLBACK_REDIRECT_URL
  value: "/dashboard"
- variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_FORCE_REDIRECT_URL
  value: "/membercard/onboarding"
- variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_FORCE_REDIRECT_URL
  value: "/dashboard"
- variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL
  value: "/sign-in"
- variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL
  value: "/sign-up"
- variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL
  value: "/sign-in"

Furthermore,
this is my middleware:
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/sign-in(.*)', '/sign-up(.*)','/','/api/webhooks(.*)','/api/wallet(.*)','/membercard/profiles(.*)']);
const isOnboardingRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/membercard/onboarding']);
const isAdminRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/admin(.*)']); // New route matcher for admin routes

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req: NextRequest) => {
  const { userId, sessionClaims, redirectToSignIn } = auth();
  console.log("Middleware triggered for URL:", req.url);

  // Check for admin routes
  if (isAdminRoute(req)) {
    if (!userId) {
      return redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: req.url });
    }
    if (sessionClaims?.metadata?.role !== 'admin') {

      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.url));
     
    }
  }

  if (userId && isOnboardingRoute(req)) {
    console.log("User is authenticated and on onboarding route.");
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!userId && !isPublicRoute(req)) {
    console.log("User is not authenticated and route is not public. Redirecting to sign-in.");
    const redirectUrl = new URL(req.url, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL);
    console.log("Redirect URL:", redirectUrl); 
    return redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: redirectUrl.toString() });
  }

  if (userId && !sessionClaims?.metadata?.onboardingComplete) {
    const onboardingUrl = new URL("/membercard/onboarding", req.url);
    return NextResponse.redirect(onboardingUrl);
  }

  if (userId && !isPublicRoute(req)) return NextResponse.next();
  console.log("User is authenticated and route is protected. Allowing access.");
  return NextResponse.next();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};

Clerk support gave me this answer:
"o this error
clerk.browser.js:2 Clerk: Redirect URL https://0.0.0.0:8080/dashboard is not on one of the allowedRedirectOrigins, falling back to the default redirect URL.
Tells me that there is a network issue, is this on K8, Docker, or is Firebase host have Network controls... You need to forward the host domain in the headers most likely.
It wouldnt hurt to double check youre using the Production keys and set them in the Firebase hosting variables
"
I've checked all environment variables and àfter carefull revision they seem to be correct, except for the webhook secret, however after fixing this the issue still persists;
I am kind of a noobie in Nextjs so please excuse me for that. How would I go with fixing this issue?
these are some logs from the cloud console:
2024-08-13 07:31:04.796 CEST
User is not authenticated and route is not public. Redirecting to sign-in.
2024-08-13 07:31:04.796 CEST
Redirect URL: URL {  }
2024-08-13 07:31:04.949 CEST
GET307378 B9 msGoogle https://t-4011972723---enigmamembers-backend-fxedffxlpa-uc.a.run.app/dashboard?_rsc=2qkwf 
2024-08-13 07:31:04.957 CEST
Middleware triggered for URL: https://0.0.0.0:8080/dashboard
2024-08-13 07:31:04.959 CEST
User is not authenticated and route is not public. Redirecting to sign-in.
2024-08-13 07:31:04.959 CEST
Redirect URL: URL {  }
2024-08-13 07:31:05.542 CEST
GET200640 B41 msGoogle https://t-4011972723---enigmamembers-backend-fxedffxlpa-uc.a.run.app/sign-in?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8080%2Fmembercard 
2024-08-13 07:31:05.544 CEST
GET2001.1 KB42 msGoogle https://t-4011972723---enigmamembers-backend-fxedffxlpa-uc.a.run.app/sign-in?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8080%2Fdashboard 

